# Color Code shape map using value ranges power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am unable to color US States in power bi shape map based on color ranges.
An aggregated metric is calculated based on all screen filters then it is mapped to color ranges to assign color, as adding a measure in legend field of the chart is not possible I am unable to color it.
Is Power BI dev team planning to include the feature to allow adding measure as the legend or there is any other possible way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could always create an image and use that as your legend

Comment: @StelioK my concern is based on coloring the map not on showing the legend